# GCP LB with static website and kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to migrate an application from AWS to Googles container engine. 
I have an S3 website (static files) living at my.domain.example and a backend living at the same url, but at the /api path. Basically, i route traffic to the backend if the /api path exists, otherwisie, i use the s3 site.

On gcp, its possible to do this with a load balancer, as it can have a backend  cluster target and a backend bucket (storage) which is a static website. The problem however is that the loadbalancer is created using kubernetes ingress.
I have tried to manually add the bucket target to the LB but it looks like GKE goes back and overrides the configuration. 
Is there anyway I can have a k8s backend cluster and a google-storage website live on the same domain, but different paths, in google cloud?

Comment: There seems to be an open issue in github for Kubernetes to support storage bucket backend or allow manual change, so far it is not possible 
 - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/353

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use a Storage Bucket as a backend service of a load balancer in GKE at the moment.
With the 1.19 version of kubernetes should be possible but GKE did not reach that version yet.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes